# Page not reloading via 'back' when using pushState() / onpopstate

Tags: javascript, html, pushstate

I am refreshing some pages with AJAX and so an updating the history with the following code -

```
/** Update the page history */
var pushState_object = {
    ajax_string: ajax_string,
    security: security,
};
window.history.pushState(pushState_object, title, permalink);
```

I am then calling this onPopState function on page load -

```
window.onpopstate = function(e){
    if(window.history.state !== null){
        initiate_load_updated_page(window.history.state.ajax_string, window.history.state.security, 0)
    }
}
```

I am having a slight problem though using the back button when going from a page where the content was generated through AJAX to a page that was loaded in the usual way. The URL will change, but the page will not reload. Clicking back again takes me to the page before, as I would expect, and then going forward works fine - it is just that one situation where the back button does not work.

Any suggestions here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The initial state does not have a `.state` property available, because you didn't use `.pushState` to add such data (it was loaded the normal way as you describe).

What you do know though, is that if there is no `.state`, it must be the original state, so you can use an `else` block like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/CCgDn/1/.

Lastly, you can use `e.state`.

```
window.onpopstate = function(e){
    if(e.state !== null) { // state data available
        // load the page using state data
        initiate_load_updated_page(e.state.ajax_string, window.history.state.security, 0);

    } else { // no state data available
        // load initial page which was there at first page load
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, the way you explained it helped me understand the problem. Rather than use `else` suggested, I used `replaceState()` on the page when it was initially loaded to ensure that the correct `.state` existed. I did this because I'm really not sure how else I would have been able to reload the contents of the page through JS. Possibly not the most elegent way of doing it, but it works. Thanks for you assistence.

Comment: @DavidGard can you please show how you solved this... I am having a similar problem and I'm not sure on how to use `replaceState()` for solving it

Comment: @NickGinato - Wow, this was like a year and a half ago! I'll try and dig something out, but no promises.

Comment: In the above solution, if anyone else is struggling, just change the initiate_load_updated_page line to location.reload();
Thanks.